# Sonar successfully executed, no code coverage reported

Tags: java, ant, build, build-automation, sonarqube

I have a java-project that I wish to do some analysis on using Sonar.

I have a build.xml file with a target called sonar that just points out where my sonar-ant-task.jar-file is located, and this is the rest:

```
<sonar:sonar workDir="${source.path}" key="${ant.project.name}" version="${version}" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">
```

When I run it I get this:

sonar:

```
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
[sonar:sonar] Sonar Ant Task version: 1.0
[sonar:sonar] Sonar work directory: PATH/src
[sonar:sonar] Sonar server: http://localhost:9000
[sonar:sonar] Sonar version: 3.0.1
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:47.958 INFO      o.s.c.p.Database - Create JDBC datasource
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:48.672 INFO  actDatabaseConnector - Initializing Hibernate
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:50.700 INFO  .s.b.b.ProjectModule - -------------  Analyzing package
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.407 INFO  .s.b.ProfileProvider - Selected quality profile : [name=Sonar way with Findbugs,language=java]
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.426 INFO  nPluginsConfigurator - Configure maven plugins...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.549 INFO        org.sonar.INFO - Compare to previous analysis (2012-10-15)
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.588 INFO        org.sonar.INFO - Compare over 5 days (2012-10-10, analysis of 2012-10-15 09:09:26.826)
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.621 INFO        org.sonar.INFO - Compare over 30 days (2012-09-15, analysis of 2012-10-15 09:09:26.826)
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.664 INFO  .b.p.SensorsExecutor - Initializer ProjectFileSystemLogger...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.668 INFO  .b.p.SensorsExecutor - Initializer ProjectFileSystemLogger done: 4 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.679 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.713 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 34 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.713 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor SquidSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.745 INFO  .s.p.s.SquidExecutor - Java Squid scan...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.749 INFO  .s.p.s.SquidExecutor - Java Squid scan done: 4 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.749 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor SquidSensor done: 36 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.750 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor SurefireSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.751 INFO  s.p.s.SurefireSensor - parsing PATH\src\target\surefire-reports
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.757 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 7 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.757 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor CpdSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.757 INFO        org.sonar.INFO - SonarEngine is used
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.758 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:51.758 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProfileSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.403 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProfileSensor done: 645 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.404 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.435 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 31 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.436 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.465 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 29 ms
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.750 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Execute decorators...
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.910 INFO  .b.p.UpdateStatusJob - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.911 INFO  b.p.PostJobsExecutor - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.969 INFO  b.p.PostJobsExecutor - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.982 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2012-09-17 and 2012-10-15
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:52.984 INFO  DefaultPeriodCleaner - <- Delete snapshot: 2012-10-15T09:11:13+0200 [463]
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:53.006 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2011-10-17 and 2012-09-17
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:53.006 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2007-10-22 and 2011-10-17
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:53.007 INFO  .d.p.DeleteAllFilter - -> Delete data prior to: 2007-10-22
[sonar:sonar] 09:16:53.011 INFO  o.s.c.purge.PurgeDao - -> Clean package [id=404]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
```

When I browse to `http://localhost:9000` I can see the Sonar dashboard with my project but no lines analyzed, it's all empty and code coverage says '-'.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any configuration options in you build.xml under the sonar:sonar tag?

It seems that you use the Sonar Ant task v1.0. In this case you have to define where your source code is according to [this wiki page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task+1.0).

If you are new to Sonar, maybe you should try the [Sonar Ant task v2.0](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Sonar+Ant+Task).

Comment: Thanks so much for you input, in the end it was all about adding some properties to my ant-file (sonar.projectKey, projectName, sources, binaries...) and it just worked.

Comment: @marko The ANT task changed dramatically after version 1.o. It's very old and not officially supported by the latest release of Sonar.